# Mask first 6 digits with javascript when writing to a list

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I have a search form that when the user searches by name, it returns account numbers, full name and SSN. I am using Ajax to POST the form and handle the data return. In the Ajax post, it builds a list and the list is written to the screen in a `div`. Is there a way to mask the first 6 digits of the SSN when the list is being written?

Here is the POST:

```
//Submit form
$(function submit() {
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Home/TAPost',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                var options = data;
                $each(options, function (index, option) {
                    $("#resultsList").append('<li>' + response[option] + '</li>');
                });
               }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

DIV being written to:

```
<section id="searchResults">
    <h2>Search Results</h2>
    <ul id="resultsList"></ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Does the user have a reason to ever see the complete SSN? If you're going to mask it, why are you transmitting it and storing it on the client machine? Depending on caching and encryption, and the country it's in (since you have a US Army icon I'm assuming US) you might even be breaking the law. My recommendation is filter it server-side.

Comment: The user will need to see it for authentication of the caller. Is your suggestion to mask it on the the return from the DB?

Comment: There is absolutely zero way to ever 100% prevent someone from unmasking this data on the client, which is precisely why you SHOULDN'T mask it on the client.  You should mask on the server before returning the data.

Comment: Yeah. If they only need to ever see the last-4, only send the last 4 from the DB. I could press F12, and see all network traffic in most browsers, so even if you mask it, I could grab every SSN and write them down. Honestly what I've done in the past is I created a computed column called LastFourOfSSN. That way someone can't forget to mask it. Even better, we used to have a view in the DB that had it pre-masked. Only certain user accounts had access to the real table with unmasked data.

Comment: I hope _my_ SSN hasn't made it into your database...

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with Social Security Numbers you need to be careful. Sending this data to the browser leaves it vulnerable. Even if we're using HTTPS, and have browser caching disabled, most browsers include a network window that lets me see the traffic coming to my browser. As a result, I could see the result of your AJAX call and all of the unmasked SSNs. In IE, for example, I press F12, and go to the Network tab and boom, an identity thief's dream!

You should mask the data as close to the point of origin as possible. Meaning, if all I need is the last 4, why even send the full SSN from the DB to my web server? That means it's stored in my web-server unmasked. Someone examining the memory of the web server could see it. What you should do is only send the last 4 from the DB or whatever the point of origin is. That way you expose the data to the least amount of exposure possible.

In the past I've stored the SSN and the Masked SSN in separate fields. That way it's not up to the person writing the stored procedure to mask it. They should just select the masked field. You could even create a view called "view_UserDataMasked" and give your IIS/web-server username access to this view, but not access to the "table_UserData" which would have the full SSN. That would help prevent the potential of a SQL injection from ever revealing SSNs too.

Also, I hope it goes without saying, the SSNs should be stored in the DB encrypted along with encrypted DB backups. When you're dealing with protected personal information you need to be careful. A hack could cost you/your company millions of dollars in damages.